# Is it possible to send message to dynamically constructed JMS/WS endpoint in Aqualogic Service Bus?

Tags: dynamic, proxy, endpoint, alsb

Aqualogic Service Bus allows creating "business" services for specific end points, but what if the end point is not defined during configuration time or even the number of end points is not fixed.

Is it possible to send message to dynamically constructed JMS/WS endpoint in Aqualogic Service Bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared to be possible through using a "Routing options" actions inside "Service call-out" and specifying custom XQyery inside "URI" box.